# Handling a download url results in 404

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a single page web app using React and React-router v4 that is being served and consuming API from a golang backend.

The issue is: the client is requesting a download link for a file in the form `hostname:port/download/file_name`, however since the backend is running on the same hostname:port (served statically), react-router is handling the download link as an in-app navigation so it results in the frontend's 404

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={WelcomeScreen} />
        <Route path='/grades' component={LevelYearScreen} />
        <Route path='/grade/:gradeId' component={SubjectScreen} />
        <Route path='/subject-:subjectId/term-:termIndex' component={LessonSectionsScreen} />
        <Route path='*' component={NotFoundPage} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Once the URL has been fetched, I'm navigating to the URL in order to download the file

```
window.location.href = response.fileUrl;
```

I have also tried to use `<a href="fileUrl"/>` and react-router's `<Redirect>` nothing seems to work. If the link is copied and pasted manually to the browser's address bar, the same thing happens. But if the js bundle is not present in the cache (Private window for example) the file is downloaded normally.

Is there any way to exclude the "/download" route from react-router ?

Comment: you can set it up so that when an specific endpoint is reached, you will not serve the react part. or you can serve another react component. i dont have any background with golang but i believe this can be done the same way as express

Comment: I've made an edit to say that backend's "/download" endpoint works as expected if called, but in my case it's handled by the client side and it's not being forwarded to the backend

Comment: Not from the client. You probably have your backend server to pass all routes (*) to `index.html`. You'll need to make an exception on your server for when the user requests `/download`.